# update data saved in an array in my frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux

the problem here is that i bring my friend list from backend and i stored it in an array in frontend so i can use it but when  a user in my friend list update his picture it didn't update in the my list so the challenge here for me is that i want a way to update this data in array i figure a way but it work on click only so this is not acceptable for good user experience and this should by dynamically and i also i tried socket io but this data is already stored in my array so i can't see socket is going to be useful in this any one face a problem like this before and if there is a better way please tell me , i worked with react,redux,mongodb and Node

```
exports.getFriendList = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let user = req.user;
    const myFriendList = await Friend.findOne({ user: user.id });
    io.emit('get friend', myFriendList);
    res.json(myFriendList);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message });
  }
};
```

this is how data come from database the follower and following array remain the same after other user update there image i tried to get my friend list after i update my image with socket io as a test but it didn't work
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want the images to update in the front-end autonomously upon update, Socket.io (or similar websocket library) is precisely what you need.

Your objective is to establish listeners for updating a profile image, and emitting a message to those listening out for that event.

You seem to be very concerned about the images already being in the array in the frontend, but there's no reason you can't modify the array after it is initialised.

For arguments sake, your emit could be something like this:

```
app.post(`/api/update-avatar`, function (req, res) => {

//Deal with updating the image here
//............


//Then emit the image
io.emit(`user-image-updated`, {userId: 2, userAvatar: yyyyyyyyy})

})
```

Your front-end listener could look something like this:

```
const FriendList = (props) => {
  const [friends, setFriends] = React.useState([
    { userId: 1, userAvatar: null, userId: 2, userAvatar: null },
  ]);

  socket.on(`user-image-updated`, (data) => {
    setFriends((currentListOfFriends) => {
      return currentListOfFriends.map((eachFriend) => {
        if (eachFriend.userId == data.userId) {
          return data;
        } else {
          return eachFriend;
        }
      });
    });
  });

  return (
    <ul>
      {friends.map((friend) => (
        <li>
          <img src={friend.userAvatar} />
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Comment: i did that but it bring me the data with the old image not with the new one

Comment: That most probably means you emitted the message before the writing of the new image was complete.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question isn’t that clear,
There many ways to about this...
You could use socket to send the friend list, so whenever a new data comes from your server it replaces the existing data in the friend list  array in your frontend.